# Grouped Horizontal Button Group in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I was wondering if there was any way to achieve this look in Android natively: 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html

In particular I'm looking for the outer buttons to have rounded edges while the inner buttons are perfectly rectangular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make Shape file for each. just create the Shape file with the defining the corner radius for specific button and use it.

for example top button 1

set the button background like this way

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn1" android:text="Click" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/mycorner"/>
```

create the different xml file for different shape in drawable folder like here mycorner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
                android:topRightRadius="8dip"
                android:topLeftRadius="1dip"
                android:bottomRightRadius="1dip"
                />
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
    <gradient android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make three buttons, set them like so:

`android:layout_width="0dip"`

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

`android:layout_weight="1"`

This will evenly space each button. As for round corners, there are numerous examples already on here, just search. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+round+button+corners